# How do I get Azure to let my WebAPI controller return 404?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles

I have a WebAPI controller that returns an empty 404 response when an entity isn't found, and a 200 when it is.  This works fine when running in my local DevFabric, but when deployed I get a 500 instead of a 404.  The 200 use case works in both environments.

```
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var result = getEntity(id);

        if (result == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Why am I not getting my 404 when deployed to Azure?

Comment: Do you get any error details in the 500 response message?

Comment: There was a bit of generic text that an error had occurred - no details.

Comment: Is NotFound() your custom method. This can happen due to exception filters overriding the error if NotFound is thrown as exception.

Comment: @Chandermani No, that's part of WebAPI

Answer (score 2):

With the level of information you provided I can suggest yo to remote debug your application from Azure Webrole - http://antirandom.com/2012/09/20/remotely-debugging-a-windows-azure-webrole-via-visual-studio-debugger/

To my understanding 500 is your Web API internal server server. So debugging would help you to find out. Also you can enable Azure Web Role Logging - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn186185.aspx

Comment: Thanks - I ended up enabling remote desktop and hitting the service from within the machine.  That led me to the problem - IIS on Server 2012 already has mime type mappings for mp4 and m4v, while my IIS didn't, so there were mappings in the web.config to add them.  Removing them from web.config allowed the 404 to come through.  I'm not sure why it was serving the 200 response correctly.